# convert requests OAuth2Session to google oauth2 Credentials

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-oauth

I have built a flask app that authorises a user using [`flask_dance`'s google blueprint](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/quickstarts/google.html)

I would like to use that user's authorisation to access GCS using the [GCS Client](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/)

How can I convert a
[`requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session`](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#oauth-2-0-session) (returned by `flask_dance`)
to a [`google.auth.credentials.Credentials`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html) (needed by google cloud libs) which would make this possible?

the token in the OAuth2Session looks like this:

```py
{
    'id_token': 'eyJh....',
    'access_token': 'ya29.Glw....',
    'expires_at': 1561605616.261379,
    'expires_in': 3573.162272,
    'scope': [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'openid',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
    ],
    'token_type': 'Bearer'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to extract the Access Token and create new credentials with it.

```
// Grab the Access Token from the OAuth Flow
access_token = resp.json()["access_token"]

// Create new credentials with the Access Token
credentials = google.auth.credentials.Credentials(access_token)
```

Note: In your OAuth Flow, you must include a Google Cloud Storage Scope. You will need to modify your `make_google_blueprint` to include a scope for Cloud Storage. Examples:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
```

Comment: works, thanks! didn't need to add any more scope though. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` is an umbrella scope for (nearly) all of gcp

Comment: @marengaz - I missed that you had cloud-platform present in the returned parameters. Need my glasses.